# Opening image from photos lollipop Android

Tags: android, image, download, image-gallery, photos

I'm trying to open an image for display in my app. This initially worked with any local files with the code below:

```
...
if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
...

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, when I open an image using lollipop from the uploaded photos galley, the image seems to be downloaded, but the "_data" returns null and therefore I can't find the local address to open in my app.

My question: How do I open an image that is downloaded from the photos galley?

I've read a lot about isMediaDocument and isDownloadedDocument but all return false for the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
* Created by HP-HP on 09-08-2015.
*/
public class ImagePathUtils {

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;


    // Google Drive Uri
    if(isGoogleDriveUri(uri))
    {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
        try {
            parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inDither = false;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
            bmOptions.inInputShareable = true;

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor,null,bmOptions);
            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            return storeGoogleDriveImage(context,image).getPath();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static Uri storeGoogleDriveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    File pictureFile = ImageUtils.getOutputMediaFile(context,"share");
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d("","Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return Uri.parse("file://" + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is GoogleDrive.
 */
public static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
    //com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy from google drive share to bakar
    //com.google.android.apps.docs.storage from bakar  publish activity to google drive
    return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I open an image that is downloaded from the photos galley?

That depends on what "open an image" means.

If your objective is to show the image in an `ImageView` or some similar widget, use any of the available [image loading libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Picasso or Universal Image Loader. They will handle doing this work on a background thread, caching, and such for you.

If you have a need to work with the image more directly, use `openInputStream()` on your `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` to the image, to get an `InputStream` on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
```

}

if it not works. I think u open google+ drive photo gallery not the phone storage galery. i have same problem in past using lollipop. i change my intent of calling gallery and it works